# Show kernel stack usage for a process in Linux

Tags: linux, process

I am trying to determine how much kernel stack is being used by processes on a server. I found [a document](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LinuxSupport/SysReqDiagnosis) that indicates that the output from sysrq-t shows the amount of unused stack in the 4th field of the line with the process name. The problem is, every machine I run the sysrq-t on except an old, 32-bit CentOS 5 box always has 0 for this field. Is there another way to determine the stack usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that value to be populated the kernel must be compiled with `CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE`. I suspect most production kernels do not set it.

```
# RHEL5
$ grep CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE /boot/config-`uname -r`
# CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE is not set

# Lucid
$ grep CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE /boot/config-`uname -r`
# CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE is not set

# Precise
$ grep CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE /boot/config-`uname -r`
# CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE is not set
```

Comment: Any idea if there's another way to get the stack usage information without recompiling with the CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE option?